# Spring security with Html pages and Rest web service authentication

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, authentication

I'm using Spring security and database login in my application (in the future I'll have to implement LDAP authentication).
Through web all work right, but now when I call web services from external (I have some web service for internal javascript and some for external calls) I receive the HTML code of login page. It's correct, but now how can I make REST call?
I have to protect them, I thought to use a token or username and password for each web services call, but how can I set username and password in REST call?
For example with postman. Then I will set the credentials also in

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForEntity(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?filePath={filePath}", byte[].class, filePath);
```

and in

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
ContentBody cbPath= new StringBody(toStorePath,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
builder.addPart("file", cbFile);
builder.addPart("toStorePath",cbPath);
httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

On the web I have even the roles for the user, maybe I'll have to use them also for the web services.
Thanks for the advices. Regards
UPDATE:
As @Gergely Bacso advices me, I have updated my code, but now I have the opposite problems: When I call web services they return all the information without username and password.
This is security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/client/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
                    .ignoring()
                        .antMatchers("/static/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
                        //.antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                       // .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, it is a bit confusing now. You need to be clear on *what* are you protecting exactly? If it is a REST service, then you need http-basic. If it is a webpage, you probably need form login. *If you have both* you need to configure both auth methods for the different resources. Based on your original post I understood you have only REST services. This might be incorrect.

Comment: Yes I have both, web service and page. Web service are called from pages or from java class imported in Matlab

Comment: Right. In that case this is what you are working on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-cookies-for-web-annotat

Comment: Are you suggesting to use form authentication for web service except for those that are called from external? And if one of this external web services calls one interna web service, it works? I updated main post

Comment: Yes. The resources consumed by application like /REST/* should be protected by http-basic, the webpages protected by form-login. At least that is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question asked only a few days ago:

[Securing REST service with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002878/securing-rest-endpoint-using-spring-security/34300189)

The important part is that:

> In case you want to secure something that is accessed programatically (for example a REST service being called by another program) then **you should not use form-based authentication.**

What you need is something much more suitable for the job. Like an HTTP-basic auth. Form-based login methods are more suited to use cases where users can enter their username/password.